# OnUpdating, the previous record occurs, how to tackle this in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql-server

I have many text fields in HTML, and when i update the fields, it gets updated in db, but the sheet which appears come with previous record, i have to manually refresh the browser to see the updated record, how can i tackle this situation, that after updating, the updated record should come in fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reload the fields from the db after the update. that way you'll also know if anything went wrong while saving to the db

Comment: @Muhammad I'm not sure if that would really help. Your page will still preform a postback. Best to refill it in the page_load

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rebind all HTML fileds with updated record by fetching new values from db.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebind your controls again with the data. Only then you will get the updated data.
You may use Updatepanel if you want.